# error bound in function approximation algorithm

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-science, approximation, floating-point

Suppose we have the set of floating point number with "m" bit mantissa and "e" bits for exponent. Suppose more over we want to approximate a function "f".

From the theory we know that usually a "range reduced function" is used and then from such function we derive the global function value.

For example let x = (sx,ex,mx) (sign exp and mantissa) then... log2(x) = ex + log2(1.mx) so basically the range reduced function is "log2(1.mx)".

I have implemented at present reciprocal, square root, log2 and exp2, recently i've started to work with the trigonometric functions. But i was wandering if given a global error bound (ulp error especially) it is possible to derive an error bound for the range reduced function, is there some study about this kind of problem? Speaking of the log2(x) (as example) i would lke to be able to say...

"ok i want log2(x) with k ulp error, to achieve this given our floating point system we need to approximate log2(1.mx) with p ulp error"

Remember that as i said we know we are working with floating point number, but the format is generic, so it could be the classic F32, but even for example e=10, m = 8 end so on.

I can't actually find any reference that shows such kind of study. Reference i have (i.e. muller book) doesn't treat the topic in this way so i was looking for some kind of paper or similar. Do you know any reference?

I'm also trying to derive such bound by myself but it is not easy...

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sin, \cos$ are periodic and bounded for real arguments, your error depends mainly on the range reduction $\pmod {2\pi}$ or $\pmod {\pi/2}.$ This is tricky 
because you must know all the $2^e + O(1)$ bits of $2/\pi$ to get a reliable result. For trigonmetric redution you can use the so-called Payne/Hanek reduction, see e.g. K.C. Ng, Argument Reduction for Huge Arguments: Good to the Last Bit, Technical report, SunPro, 1992, available from http://www.validlab.com/arg.pdf

Comment: I don't understand a think in the range reduction... why is always referred to the trigonometric functions and not for other functions. I've seen an analysis referred to additive range reduction in the muller book, but i have never seen something related to the multiplicative range reduction. looks like the other functions are not of interest for the error analysis. Is it my impressions?

Comment: This is not restricted to trigonometric functions, but applies  to all periodic function with irrational or transcendental period (e.g. elliptic integrals etc). Simply speaking: If you do not have a reliable range reduction you will leave most or all phase information and the absolute error can be $\pm 100 \%$.

Comment: But i mean... as you said it applies to all periodic function... what i was wandering (just out of curiosity) if there's anything related to log and exp for example, about how much a poor range reduction could influence the final result.

Comment: An example: Looking at $\exp(x)$ in binary arithmetic you should know some constant like $\log_2(e)$ with increased precision (and perform some pseudo multi precision operations, Cody/Waite in Muller's book) since you compute $2^{i+f}$ where $i,f$ are integer and fractional part of $x \log_2(e).$ Here the errors in the fractional part are directly related to the error in the mantissa of the result, if there is no increased precision the number of bits that go into the integer part will be lost for the fractional part.

Comment: That's a good point... why i need increased precisions? it's the same question for the trig functions...

Comment: Example $e^x=2^{x\log_2(e)}$ with 6 digits, $x=8.1, \; e^{8.1}= 3294.47$. 
We have $\log_2(e) = 1.44270 = 1.4375 + 0.519504\times 10^{-2}$, where $1.4375$ is exact.
Without increased precision: If you compute $8.1\times 1.44270 = 11.6859$ you get $e^x=2^{11.6859}= 3294.63$.

The second method using the two constants gives:
$1.4375\times 8.1 = 11.64375,\quad$
$0.519504\times 10^{-2}\times 8.1 = 0.420798\times 10^{-1}\quad$

$$e^x=2^{11}\times2^{0.64375+0.420798\times 10^{-1}}=2^{11}\times2^{0.685830}=3294.47$$

Comment: Which criteria did you use to split the log2(e)?

Comment: The larger part should be exactly representable and not have full bits
$1.4375 = 184/128$

Comment: So the idea is... take the constant C of n digits, split C = C1 + C2, where C1 is the nearest number representable by the system to C while C2 is the remeinder with the same digit number (maybe i should say with the same precision since the exponent is stored apart)?

Comment: (I've just read the Cody/Waite algorithm, the reference says that sometimes the input could be splitted in C = C1 + C2 + C3, which split criteria should be adopted in such case?)

Comment: I share your understanding of the basic idea, I think the decision two or three constants depends on actual data (bit size of float, bits needed,  ranges etc)

Comment: but what i was wandering in this case was...
in the basic case C1 > C2, as i described and you confermed before, is the last case should C1 > C2 > C3 too? is there some study on this stuff?

Comment: I am not aware of such studies, I only use the ideas in actual implementations, but the crucial requirement is: If $c=c_1+c_2+c_2$ then the products $k\times c_i$ should be exactly representable and the subtractions in
$x_{r} = x-k\times c = ((x-k\times c_1) - k\times c_2)) -k\times c_3$
must not introduce new errors.

Comment: Some other question... but i don't really if it makes any sense... anyway... i was wandering if there is a version of such algorithm but referred to the multiplicative range reduction. Like $x_r = \frac{x}{C_1} \frac{C_1}{C_2}$ so far and so forth... is there something like this?